# How to transfer bitcoins from blockchain.info?

Tags: blockchain.info

I want to transfer bitcoins from blockchain but I don't know how. I have a bither and I want to transfer it there. How to transfer bitcoins from blockchain.info to bither?

Comment: Have you tried sending them to your bither wallet?

Comment: Blockchain.info also has more than one service. Are you using a mobile wallet, or browser wallet?